# ClosedXML and digits as text

Tags: sql, excel, closedxml

I am using `ClosedXML` to export data from SQL Data Table to Excel.

This is part of exporting: (dt is a datatable with data from SQL Server)

```
 using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xlsx");
                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
```

The problems are:

- After exporting all digits are as text
- Decimal digits have a dot but should have a comma

Please, could somebody help me how to correctly format my export to Excel ?

Comment: What datatype have the columns in your `SQL` and in the `DataTable`?

Answer (score 2):

Might Help [ClosedXmlDocumetnation](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Inserting%20Tables&referringTitle=Documentation)

Map the datatable with DataTypes

```
     private DataTable GetTable()
    {

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));


        return table;
    }

        // From a DataTable
        var dataTable = GetTable();
        ws.Cell(7, 1).Value = "From DataTable";
        var tableWithData = ws.Cell(8, 1).InsertTable(dataTable.AsEnumerable());
        ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();

        wb.SaveAs("InsertingTables.xlsx");
```

or

```
            dataTable.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(Int32);
            dataTable.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(string);
            dataTable.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(Int32);

        //after this 
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
```